# Process.register Not Applying to Atom

Tags: elixir

I am currently trying to make an atom for a database connection to Redis. Usually I would use the `name` option in `start` of `GenServer`, but that is not available. In the Getting Started (Elixir 1.0.5), the example seems to show `Process.register(pid, :kv)` as an option. Maybe there is a better option to make this process accessible?

Following is showing how it doesn't match the guard in query for the connection client.

```
iex(2)> redis_client = Exredis.start
#PID<0.367.0>
iex(3)> Process.register(redis_client, :redis_client)
true
iex(4)> :redis_client |> Exredis.query ["GET", "test"]
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Exredis.query/2
    (exredis) lib/exredis.ex:95: Exredis.query(:redis_client, ["GET", "test"])
iex(4)> redis_client |> Exredis.query ["GET", "test"] 
:undefined
iex(5)> redis_client |> Exredis.query ["SET", "test", "value"]
"OK"
iex(6)> redis_client |> Exredis.query ["GET", "test"]         
"value"
iex(7)> :redis_client
:redis_client
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error most likely comes from [these lines](https://github.com/artemeff/exredis/blob/master/lib/exredis.ex#L95) in ExRedis' source:

```
def query(client, command) when is_pid(client) and is_list(command), do:
    client |> :eredis.q(command) |> elem(1)
```

As you can see, `start_link/2` only accepts a pid as the first argument (`when is_pid(client)`).

You can use [`Process.whereis/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#whereis/1) to find the pid of a registered process and pass that to ExRedis:

```
iex> :redis_client |> Process.whereis |> Exredis.query(["SET", "test", "value"])
"OK"
```

Comment: Thank you whatyouhide =). I thought when it registered, it would be the process_id/process, and not a name of the process.

Comment: Someone should likely open up an issue on ExRedis, they shouldn't limit it to pids really.